# php search, show php template based on search return

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am still learning and any help would be appreciated. HTML is pretty bare bones. No styles or anything like that yet, all on just localhost for testing. So I do not have a example set up live.

I am using just PHP and a table in phpmyadmin. The files I have are index.php(form is here), search.php(search code stored here), provider1.php, provider2.php, provider3.php, provider4.php.

So far I have a table that is stored with these columns:Provider,state full name, city, state, zip code. I have a search form that users enter a zip code and if the zip code matches a row in the table, it looks at the provider, checks which one it is (provider1, provider2, provider3, provider4).On the search.php it echos out how many choices they have, where the city state is from the zip code and then also echos the zip code that they entered.

My question is how can I tell it so if that zip code has a provider, to use that provider.php. Example:

92804 = provider1, so then use provider1.php and also still echo out they city and state that goes with that zip code.

index.php:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>search</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="zipcode..."/>
    <input type="submit" value=">>"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

search.php:

```
 <?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("could not connect");
mysql_select_db("zipcodes") or die("could not find db");

//collect
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_GET['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `Zip Code` = '$searchq'") or die("could not search");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'There was no search results!!';
    }else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $city = $row['City'];
            $state = $row['State'];
            $provider = $row['Provider Name'];

            $output = '<div> '.$provider.' '.$city.' '.$state.' </div>';
        }
    }

}

switch ($provider) {
    case "provider1":
        //put code here that tells it to use provider1.php
        break;
    case "provider2":
        //put code here that tells it to use provider2.php
        break;
    case "provider3":
        //put code here that tells it to use provider3.php
        break;
    case "provider4":
        //put code here that tells it to use provider4.php
        break;
    default:
        echo "No provider, try again";
}



?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $provider ?> in <?php echo $city ?>, <?php echo $state ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    This is just a results page for testing. This page needs to know what zip to match to a provider, then go to that page.
    <p>You have <?php echo $count ?> choices</p>
    <p>Your provider is <?php echo $provider ?></p>
    <p>You are located in <?php echo $city ?>, <?php echo $state ?> </p>
    <p>The zip code you searched was <?php echo $searchq ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

provider1.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $provider ?> in <?php echo $city ?>, <?php echo $state ?></title>
</head>

<body>
This would be a template for provider1
<p>You have <?php echo $count ?> choices</p>
<p>You are located in <?php echo $city ?>, <?php echo $state ?> </p>
<p>The zip code you searched was <?php echo $searchq ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible to do? or do I need to use something like laravel to get it started or some type of framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the data sets you are dealing with? Is it just pure integers between a set range?

If so you could just do something like this:

```
if($provider > 92804 && < 92806){
include 'provider1.php';
}elseif($provider > 92807 && < 92809){
include 'provider2.php';
}else{
// No provider, try again
}
```

Alternatively you may be able to use something such as the preg_match function which would probably be the better scalable solution when dealing with large data sets.

Comment: I did not know I could just use "include" and then the template that I needed. This is simple enough and does the trick. This may be for a new question, or you can point me in the right direction, when it does search, the url is /search-zip.php?search=92804. Is there a way to clean this up, I looked and it looks like something to do with php route? Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can do that, you may change it to something such as /search-zip.php/92804. To do this you could use rewrite rules, do some research on them. A term for cleaning up the URL in reference to what you mean is sometimes referred to as "pretty urls", searching this on the web will also return a number of related results to your question.